# MQTT how to stop loop after getting message

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

I have Python Tkinter UI based project. I send messages form textbox with mqtt publisher and listen them at the same time with the same client. It works but the infinite listening loop crashed my app after receiving message.

My problem is probably here

```
while 1:
      client.loop(timeout=1, max_packets= 2) #contineously checking for message
```

Tried using loop(timeout,maxpackage) but didnt work, or i did wrong.

full part of the function

```
      def func_sendanswer():

            def func_refreshconversation():
                conn = psycopg.connect("dbname=MQTTDB user=postgres host='localhost' password='pw123'")
                cur = conn.cursor()

                cur.execute("SELECT answercontent, creatorid, createddate FROM answers WHERE topicid ='"+ str(temp[0]) +"';")
                temp2 = cur.fetchall()

                text_conversation.delete("1.0","end")

                for row in temp2:
                 
                    text_conversation.insert(END, "\n" + "Kullanıcı ID: " + str(row[1]) + "\n" + "\n" + str(row[0]) +"\n" + "Tarih: " + str(row[2]) + "\n" + "___________________________________________________" + "\n")

                cur.close()        
                conn.close()

            message = text_sendmessage.get('0.0', 'end')
            tpcname = string_topicname
            print(string_topicname)

            def on_message(client, userdata, message):
                print("Gelen Mesaj:")
                print(str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")) )
                msj = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
                print("")

                conn = psycopg.connect("dbname=MQTTDB user=postgres host='localhost' password='pw123'")
                cur = conn.cursor()

                cur.execute('INSERT INTO answers(answercontent, creatorid, topicid, createddate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,current_timestamp)', (msj, online_userid, topicid))
                conn.commit()
                cur.close()        
                conn.close()

                func_refreshconversation()
                    
            client= paho.Client("user") #create client object 
            client.on_message=on_message
                
            print("connecting to broker host","localhost")
            client.connect("localhost")#connection establishment with broker
            print("subscribing begins here")    
            client.subscribe(tpcname)#subscribe topic test

            
            ret= client.publish(tpcname,message) #topic name is test

            while 1:
                    client.loop(timeout=1, max_packets= 2) #contineously checking for message
```

Comment: What exactly is the intention here, do you intent to totally disconnect the client after you receive the message or do you intend to continue to publish after you receive the message? Or is the intention is just not to block the UI?

Comment: @hardillb Yes i just want to get a single messeage and not block the UI. Because the function above is triggered by a button so i dont need to listen forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is probably wrong, Pub/Sub is not a good choice for a request/response system.

But if you really want to use it this way, then just subscribe/unsubscribe from the topic rather than try and constrain the client's network activity by messing with the loop.

Comment: Tried unsubscribing now. But it didnt stop the loop. UI still crashes.

Comment: Unsubscribing WON'T stop the loop, that's the **point**. Use the `loop_start()` function to run the loop on a separate thread and leave it running ALL THE TIME.

Comment: Thanks i finally fixed it!